# Firebase , cannot add sha1 key

Tags: firebase, sha1

I was having two apps in firebase with same project id so I deleted one and added sha-1 key, but still showing error you cannot have two projects with same id

I deleted one app from firebase

Comment: delete debug.keystore and then regenerate the keys.